# Activation account email not sent when logged in (Craft CMS)

Tags: backend, craftcms

I'm Using Craft CMS to manage different user groups.
I have setup the option for user to be able to register through a form.

If the user registers gets assigned to an specific user group. (1)

It will get the confirmation / activation email and when clicking on it this will give them the option to setup their password etc.. so that the account will be setup.

Now I have a user group (3) that has the option (when signed in) to add clients.
Basically what it does is to register a new user using only their email.

The form looks like this:

```
{% requireLogin %}

{% set loggedin = currentUser %}  
{% set requestAccess = loggedin.isInGroup('1') %}

{% if requestAccess %}
    {% redirect 'users/verify' %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}
  {{ redirectInput('users/invited') }}
  
  
  <div class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden" name="groups[]" value="3">

    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      {{ input('text', 'firstName', user.firstName ?? null, {
          id: 'firstName',
          placeholder: 'First Name'
      }) }}

      {% if user is defined %}
        {{ _self.errorList(user.getErrors('firstName')) }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
      {{ input('text', 'lastName', user.lastName ?? null, {
          id: 'lastName',
          placeholder: 'Last Name'
      }) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      {{ input('email', 'email', user.email ?? null, {
        id: 'email',
        placeholder: 'Email'
      }) }}

      {% if user is defined %}
        {{ _self.errorList(user.getErrors('email')) }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    {% endif %}

      <button class="submit-text" type="submit">Submit</button>

  </div>      
</form>
```

The form works... so when the user that is in this specific group adds a new user / invites
It gets registered on the backend and is waiting for confirmation. The problem seems that the email never goes "out".

I've tested this without being logged in, so I remove all the code related to being logged in and to confirm the user group. And this way everything seems to work just fine.

So it seems that when I'm logged in, the verification email doesn't go out.
Any idea how to solve this or how should approach it, maybe I need to bypass the "default" notification?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I think I'm facing the exact same situation.

Comment: Same here, only if I am logged in already as a different user. Odd. Going to check Craft Github.

Comment: Was nothing in Github, so I added: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/10794